# Force http to https using friendly url on htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, server

this my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitemap.php
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/img/
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.(gif|jpg|css|png|js)$|^/index\.php$)
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)$ index.php?p=$1&c=$2&t=$3&id=$4 [L,QSA]
```

I create this for using friendly url, allowing for some floders to be use like img and css folders, its working great but now I need to force  http links to https, how do I do it?

Comment: if I use  redirect rule  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] I get an error

Comment: ok, what does **an error** mean, provide details?

Comment: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 0):

just use the following code

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your full .htacess file must be like this

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitemap.php
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/img/
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.(gif|jpg|css|png|js)$|^/index\.php$)

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ /$1/$2/$3/$4 [R]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ /index.php?p=$1&c=$2&t=$3&id=$4
```

I use the same on my website : http://all4web.eu.org

Comment: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Clean your browser cookies and cache